# Nginx php-fpm "File not found" and suspect symbols

Tags: nginx

I've been stuck on an nginx configuration problem since this morning, I've literally tried everything I could find on the internet.

My problem is that I can't reach an api developped in PHP (Symfony), it gives me "File not found".

All my solution is controlled by docker containers, nginx in one and my API in another.

In my nginx configuration I've got :

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name <server_name>;
    root        /var/www/front/public;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.key;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass asmodine_front_php:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/front_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/front_access.log;
}
```

In my logs I've got :

`2020/08/17 13:56:20 [warn] 1#1: server name "/var/www/front/public/" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/conf.d/front.conf:4`

`2020/08/17 13:58:44 [error] 6#6: *22 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 108.162.229.233, server: api_multi.asmodine.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.18.0.23:9000", host: "api_multi.asmodine.com"`

I also must mention that I'm trying to duplicate a perfectly working server so all the configuration should work. But as we can see, I must have forgotten something...

Comment: Have you missed a `;` from the end of the `server_name` statement?

Comment: As you can see in my nginx configuration the `;` at the end of `server_name` is present

Comment: Ok, but the configuration file in your question is redacted, and I have no idea what the real configuration file looks like. The error message indicates that Nginx is interpreting `/var/www/front/public/` as part of the `server_name` statement. The most common cause of that error is a missing `;` which causes `root` and `/var/www/front/public/` to be added to the list of server names, and would also result in file not found errors as the `root` directive is also missing as a result.